# Encoding/Decoding using NSData+Base64.h

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, encryption, base64, nsdata

I have some encrypted data that I'm converting to a base64. I am having difficulty converting that string back into NSData that I can then use for decryption.

```
NSData *encryptedData = [self encrypt:_secretData key:[self md5data:_key] padding:&padding];
//I've tried this with different data too
NSString *cyphertext = [encryptedData base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
//this works fine
[cyphertext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
//this returns too many bytes ... it's longer than my original data
```

I'm using the standard "NSData+Base64.h" by Dave Winer - I found it on github.

Any tips on how to convert the string back to the same NSData object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using its counterparts maybe?

```
 + (NSData *) dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string
```

Note that converting to base64 must brings a multiple of 4...

Comment: I'm still getting an NSData value that is way bigger than my original encoded NSData that I pass to baseEncodingWithLineLength:. I put in NSLog statements and the NSData objects clearly have different values.

Comment: I didn't noticed first time, but `base64EncodingWithLineLength:0` looks like an abomination...

Comment: What do you mean by multiple of 4? Sorry I'm really new at this.

Comment: That's mathematic, `256/64=4`, look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more details. You should also consider accepting my answer...(the big checkmark) ;)